# Applying non-torch function on loss before calling backward()?

Tags: python, pytorch, loss-function

I want to apply a custom non-torch function on the final calculated loss before computing the gradients (calling backward()). An example would be to replace the torch.mean() on the loss vector with a custom pythonic, non-torch mean function. But doing so will break the computation graph. I can not rewrite the custom mean function using torch operators and I am at a loss as how to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: This will all depend on what type of function you're wanting to replace `torch.mean` with. As long as this function is implemented using torch operators (that provide a backward implementation), you will be able to backpropagate your loss on it. Could you define the function you want to define for us please, or is it just the mean function?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Ivan. It is a weighted mean and the weights come from another source in my code (actually another model), so implementing the mean using torch operators is not possible. I went for refactoring the mean with torch operators first, but I have come to the conclusion that it is not possible in its current implementation. So maybe the right solution would be to wrap this loss in another function/module which I'd be able to apply on the loss term, but I cannot find a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pytorch you can easily do this by inheriting from `torch.autograd.Function`: All you need to do is implement your custom `forward()` and the corresponding `backward()` methods. Because I don't know the function you intend to write, I'll demonstrate it by implementing the sine function in a way that works with the automatic differentiation. Note that you need to have a method to compute the derivative of your function with respect to its input to implement the backward pass.

```
import torch

class MySin(torch.autograd.Function):
    @staticmethod
    def forward(ctx, inp):
        """ compute forward pass of custom function """
        ctx.save_for_backward(inp)  # save activation for backward pass
        return inp.sin()  # compute forward pass, can also be computed by any other library

    @staticmethod
    def backward(ctx, grad_out):
        """ compute product of output gradient with the 
        jacobian of your function evaluated at input """
        inp, = ctx.saved_tensors
        grad_inp = grad_out * torch.cos(inp)  # propagate gradient, can also be computed by any other library
        return grad_inp
```

To use it you can use the function `sin = MySin.apply` on your input.

There is also another example worked out in the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/examples_autograd/two_layer_net_custom_function.html).